# Validation by hiding items on load and showing when error occurs on leave event

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have many books that shows me how to do Validation using the jQuery Plugin, however the project I am working on require some unorthodox approach.

In the sample code below: I added an ID to each error message holder, that because I want to call each message individually. I need to hide the entire message by removing the tag and calling the tag on ***Leave Event (if possible)*** if an error on the particular item occurs.

I wrote this piece of jQuery as an example: So instead of using the validation plugin to generate the error message, all I need it to do is show show the message on ***leave event***.

***For illustration purposes:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#signup').validate({
    rules: {
      txtUserName: {
        required: true,
        txtUserName: true
      }
    }, 
    messages: {
      txtUserName: {
        required: "Please supply your e-mail address.",
        txtUserName: "This is not a valid e-mail address."
      }
    } 
  });
});
</script>
```

***This is a basic example form:***

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="signup">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p id="flgUserName">Hide on page load but show on error</p>
      <input name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" type="text" class="required">
      <label for="txtUserName">Username:</label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <p id="flgEmail">Hide on page load but show on error</p>
      <input name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" type="text" class="required">
      <label for="txtEmail">E-mail:</label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen on "leave event"? and on leave event of what object(s)?

Comment: Thanks Roopendra: On leave event of any required object. Per class="required" Lets say the User Enters wrong data; e.g. multiple @@ sign in the email, or does not use special character in the username field or two fields don't match. then the field will display the message on a Leave Event.

I want to use the Validator plugin but instead of the generated messages, ad my own message on leave (show/hide).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's `.blur()` to figure out when a form input element loses focus.

From there, you can check to see if the form input element is valid through `formInputElement.validity.valid == true`. This only works if you have added html5's `required` attribute to each form input element.

An example of what your code might look like:

```
$('form input').blur(function() {
    if(!this.validity.valid) {
        $(this).prev().show();
    } else {
        $(this).prev().hide();
    }
});
```

Also, you may want to change the `type` attributes of the input elements so that they are validated correctly. There's a list of new types of input elements here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: I kinda plan to avoid the HTML 5 stuff for now. The support is so spotty. My plan was to use JQuery/JavaScript Validation. Just looked over a few books that have complete solutions, however, nothing mention about the Blur, which is what I needed. Thank you anyways.